# How to get to the avatar/image of a Jira user through SOAP or other means

Tags: web-services, soap, jira, avatar

I'd like to display the user avatars/images of developers registered with a Jira project. Jira has a web service API (my version is 4.2), but unfortunately I can't find an action that would extract the user avatar. There are just actions to extract project avatars.

Does anybody happen to know how to achieve this?

The user avatar can also be reached via an URL, but I need to authenticate first. I have the credentials (otherwise I wouldn't be able to make my other SOAP calls) and basic realm authentication should work, but doesn't. I am always thrown back to a login JSP. I haven't investigated from here on yet, so if someone has a cleaner idea through SOAP or however this is supposed to work in Jira thank you in advance!

Cheers, Vedran

Answer (score 7):

You can get it using the REST API, e.g. GET http://jira.atlassian.com/rest/api/latest/user?username=lmiranda (you need to be logged in to access user information in JIRA).

Example response:

```
{
   "self":"http://jira.atlassian.com/rest/api/latest/user?username=lmiranda",
   "name":"lmiranda",
   "emailAddress":"... at atlassian dot com",
   "avatarUrl":"http://jira.atlassian.com/secure/useravatar?size=large&ownerId=lmiranda",
   "displayName":"Luis Miranda [Atlassian]",
   "groups":{
      "size":5,
      "items":[

      ]
   },
   "expand":"groups"
}
```

See the [REST API Documentation](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/) for more info.

Comment: +1 I searched for an hour before I found this answer.  Exactly what I was looking for!